# Why does .erb embedding fail to insert the proper PostgreSQL password?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, ruby-on-rails-3.1, erb

I have the following config in my production `config/database.yml` file. I've noticed that this doesn't work - it fails with a postgres password authentication failure.

I also noticed that if I replace `<%= ENV['SOME_PASSWORD'] %>` with the actual password, that it works fine.

```
production:
  adapter: postgresql
  host: localhost
  database: some_database
  username: some_user
  password: <%= ENV['SOME_PASSWORD'] %>
```

**However**, I only see this behavior on my production Ubuntu server. This insertion of the environment variable works find on my OS X dev box.

Just curious why this is - why doesn't this work on Ubuntu? If I go into an interactive ruby session **on the production box** via `irb`, and type `<%= ENV['SOME_PASSWORD'] %>` it outputs the password as expected.

I've tested this multiple ways, and I'm sure this is the problem. I'm just not sure why it happens. I'm using Ruby Enterprise Edition for my ruby interpreter in both places. Just seems weird, and I'd really like to be able to keep my password completely out of my config file - I just feel like I need to use a slightly different syntax for the production server, but I'm not sure what that syntax might be.

**NOTE**: Every single other article I've found anywhere on the internet that deals with Rails postgres authentication issues, at some point, tells you to change your `pg_hba.conf` file to `trust` mode, which not only ignores the issue by bypassing authentication, it's insecure, and not a valid solution if you care about security.

Comment: Try to check an output from your production `irb`, when you load `database.yml` the [Rails way](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-2-stable/railties/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb#L115). At a first glance, it seems nothing special happens there, but who knows.

Comment: Thanks, I will check this out over the weekend and see what can be seen.